# ASP.NET State Server security

Tags: asp.net, security, session, session-state

Am i correct that when using State Server traffic between my web site and the state server isn't encrypted? If it isn't, how can i secure it (SSL)?

Comment: simply use IPSec to secure it between your systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASP.NET Session State server uses clear-text http-requests in a rest-like manner for communication. The actual protocol specification is publicly available at [[MS-ASP]: ASP.NET State Server Protocol Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc224028%28v=prot.10%29.aspx).

I've never heard of anyone encrypting the state traffic, cant find any references for it, and nothing that states that it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible for any of us to say whether the traffic between your web site and state server is encrypted or not.

At a high level, state server uses clear text for transferring the data.  But this doesn't necessarily mean it's not encrypted.

However, depending on how your network is setup it might be encrypted at a lower layer by the operating system.  Namely, if the machines are part of a domain the network administrator might have turned on the proper settings to force kerberos encryption between the machines.

Further, if you encrypt the data prior to putting it in "session" then it would obviously be encrypted.

If you are worried about internal threats then your network should be configured to encrypt all traffic between machines.  (if you want to know how, go to serverfault.com).

Comment: I would get your answer if you mentioned IPsec, but isnt Kerberos for authentication, and wont affect the actual communication?

Answer (score 0):

The state server should be behind the firewall and not public, there should be no reason to encrypt the traffic. You would only want to make sure that the traffic is only able to go to and from the web tier to the state server via network layering.

Comment: its not safe to assume anything behind a firewall is inherently safe. What if an internal sniffer was installed as has been done many times in attacks?